# Too fast insertion of data into d3 diagram with animation

Tags: javascript, animation, d3.js, visualization

I am using d3js to visualize my data. Everything works fine, when I have my "normal" code running. But now when I add animations for the insertion and deletion of elements and I insert/delete data elements too fast, then the animations of the first inserted element is not completed before the next element being inserted triggers the animations once again. Is there a way to **wait** for the animations of d3 to be completed?

Example code für an animation:

```
layoutRoot.selectAll('g')
    .data(nodes, function (d) { return d.path })
    .exit()
    .transition()
    .duration(400)
    .style('opacity', 0)
    .remove()
```

Comment: It's not clear from the description and code what the problem is.  What is the visual behaviour you wish to see?  An example with more context/code would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be a comment but I don't have the necessary reputation.

See this [d3 issue on github](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/issues/1410). Is this what you're looking for?

It's in the 3.3 milestone and the current version is 3.2.8. So, hopefully it won't be too much longer.